# Run a bash script from an R script

Tags: r, bash

So I have this programme samtools that I want to use from cmd line, converting one file to another. It works like this:

```
bash-4.2$ samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS="\t"; print ">"$1"\n"$10}' - > filename.fasta
```

As I want to automate this, I would like to automate it by using an R script. I know you can use system() to run an OS command, but I cannot get it to work by trying

```
system(samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS="\t"; print ">"$1"\n"$10}' - > filename.fasta)
```

Is it just a matter of using regexes to get rid of spaces and stuff so the comma nd argument system(command) is readable? How do I do this?

EDIT:

> system("samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS="\t"; print ">"$1"\n"$10}' - > first_batch_1.fasta")
>   Error: unexpected input in "system("samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS="\"

EDIT2:

> system("samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS=\"\t\"; print \">\"$1\"\n\"$10}' - > filename.fasta")

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {OFS="    "; print ">"$1"
awk: cmd. line:1:                         ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {OFS="    "; print ">"$1"
awk: cmd. line:1:                         ^ syntax error
>
```

EDIT3: 
And the winner is:

```
system("samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS=\"\\t\"; print \">\"$1\"\\n\"$10}' -> filename.fasta")
```

Comment: `system()` takes a character string as argument, so you need to wrap your argument in quotes.

Comment: I had tried that already. Shown as edit above.

Comment: try system("samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS=\"\t\"; print \">\"$1\"\n\"$10}' - > filename.fasta")       You need to escape the double quotation marks, in order for R to read the entire command, instead of only the command part between the first two double quotation marks

Comment: EDIT2: shows that your suggestion doesn't work. Escaping all the quotes within the awk regex makes it not work properly.

Comment: Souldn't you also escape the backslashes? `system("samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS=\"\\t\"; print \">\"$1\"\\n\"$10}' -> filename.fasta")`

Comment: You stated you want to use samtools from the commandline and the Answer from Andrie seems to be the right one. In alternative you can use two wrappers to samtools : [rbamtools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rbamtools/index.html) or [Rsamtools](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Rsamtools.html)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The way to debug this is to use `cat` to test whether your character string has been escaped correctly. So:

1. Create an object `x` with your string
2. Carefully escape all the special characters, in this case quotes and backslashes
3. Use `cat(x)` to inspect the resulting string.

For example:

```
x <- 'samtools view filename.bam | awk \'{OFS="\\t"; print ">"$1"\\n"$10}\' - > filename.fasta'

cat(x)
samtools view filename.bam | awk '{OFS="\t"; print ">"$1"\n"$10}' - > filename.fasta
```

If this gives the correct string, then you should be able to use

```
system(x)
```

Comment: Yes, I need to learn how to debug this myself. Thanks Andrie!

Comment: @Andrie i have a bash script safe in`"c:/test"` folder with name`test.sh` . I want to call this bash script in r code. I try this`system` command but getting an error dear will you help me?